# How can I load a page objects file in the rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Why can't I load a PageObject file in the rails console? I tried and got the following.

```
require "/Users/karanbirtoor/src/my_app/test/page_objects/admin_page.rb"
LoadError: cannot load such file -- selenium_helper
from /Users/karanbirtoor/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@my_app_rails3/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
```

Comment: by `load it` what do you want to do with it here? is this a test file?

Comment: No, it's supposed to be a ruby object that represents the DOM. It's used by selenium tests to interact with the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably just not getting the objects you need required beforehand. Your AdminPage object seems to include SeleniumHelper, which isn't yet required/defined in your rails console's environment. I'm betting the Selenium gem is only required in the test environment (based on its location in your Gemfile). Plus you likely have other requires happening in your test_helper.rb file.

Try this:

```
> rails console -e test
```

Then, in console

```
> require_relative "test/test_helper"
> require_relative "test/page_objects/admin_page"
> AdminPage
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. 

I was able to load the console (with "rails c test") and loading the test_helper was not an issue. But when I try loading the AdminPage I got the same error. So I tried loading the SeleniumHelper and got the following error (I already loaded the TestHelper)
    LoadError: cannot load such file -- test_helper